# JQuery button dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Here I have code where I create dynamic buttons .there is something wrong with the click event.

where I have

```
  alert("work");
```

starting with  the line above this alert,  code is not working. any help?

**Update 3**

```
   // Creating a checkbox for each category and place it in container:

    for (var i in chart.xAxis[0].categories) {

        checkboxHtml = '<label><button type ="submit" id="category' + i + '" name="category' + i + '">' + i + '</button></label>'

        $('#' + legendContainerId).append(checkboxHtml);

    }

    // Binding events to checkboxes:

    $('#' + legendContainerId + ' button[type ="submit"]').on('click', function () {


        var hiddenSeries = [];

        var hiddenCategories = [];


        // Collecting disabled categories:

         $('#' + legendContainerId + 'button[type ="submit"]').each(function (i, submit) {


            alert("work");
            if (!submit.onselect) {
                hiddenSeries[i] = null;

                hiddenCategories[i] = ' ';

            }
```

Comment: did you try type=button ?

Comment: yes but how to change the checkboxHtml?

Comment: checkboxHtml? Do explain.

Comment: see the I updatethe code .Here I used checkbox and it work .I need to use buttons insted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you want, but if all you're looking for is changing the `checkboxes` into `buttons`, then you just need to change your HTML string logic. For instance:

```
var html = '<label><button id="category' + i + '" name="category' + i + '">' + i + '</button></label>'
```

Would output:

```
<label><button id="categoryX" name="categoryX">X</button></label>
```

Where `X` is the dynamic value from your `for` loop.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/8E385/).

Comment: yah now i can see the button but still not working.I add some other code may you can see the problem.

Comment: I can assure you those buttons are clickable. What are you expecting to happen when you click on them?

Comment: I try it is not i think i have to change this      if (!checkbox.checked)    to some thing where I check if the button is have been cliked,

Comment: Instead of binding `change`, bind `click` (you should actually use `.on()`).

Comment: `$('#' + legendContainerId').on('click'...`

Comment: I fix some staff. See update3 any thing the code has some thing wrong starting before the alert..

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to change the following line:

```
$('#' + legendContainerId + 'button[type ="submit"]' + i + '"').each(function (i, submit) {
```

To:

```
$('#' + legendContainerId + ' button[type ="submit"]').each(function (i, submit) {
```

-One space char before "button[..." and "i" var removed

Comment: yes I fix the "i" .Thank you the "space char" also was problem .Now I receive the alert. Remaining the below code how to check if the button click

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically created button below works for me

```
  $(document).on('click', 'classOfButton', function (t) {
  var me= $(this).text();
  alert(me);
  })
```

Comment: how can i use that in my example ?\

Comment: use your click event in  $(document).on()